# Hiding the manual refund button in WooCommerce order

Tags: woocommerce

I have been trying to get this down all day and it is driving me crazy. I know it should be possible using `display: none;`

**I am trying to remove the "Refund Manually" Button**

[image]

Comment: why do you want to disable this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your functions.php

```
add_action('admin_head', 'remove_manual_refunds');

function remove_manual_refunds() {
  echo '<style>
    .do-manual-refund {
    display: none !important;
    }
  </style>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Tasha, this is exactly what I needed!!  It works well.